# Make a SELECT by field is empty?

Tags: abap, is-empty, opensql

I need to know how to make a comparison in a SELECT for a field that has to be empty.

I'm trying to select some fields from bkpf, with the field stblg as empty. I've done it in this way:

```
 SELECT c~kunnr a~belnr d~spart c~bldat c~waers a~hwaer f~mwskz
      INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_data
        FROM ( ( ( bsis AS f
      INNER JOIN bkpf AS a ON f~belnr = a~belnr )
      INNER JOIN bsad AS c ON c~belnr = a~belnr )
      INNER JOIN vbrk AS d ON d~vbeln = c~belnr )
      WHERE a~gjahr IN gjahr
        AND a~bukrs IN bukrs
        AND c~augdt IN augdt
        AND a~stblg = ' '
        AND f~hkont = '0034930020'.
```

Is this correct or do I have to use another thing?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, you can use `AND a~stblg = ' '` or the already mentioned `AND a~stblg EQ SPACE` - there is no difference (I would recommend to use `SPACE`. With `' '` you can't be sure, if you want to check a space or if you forgot to fill something in the '.)

On database level *empty* can have another meaning.
Databases make a difference between `space` or `' '` and *no value* (`NULL`).

You can check `NULL` in SAP with:

```
AND a~stblg IS NULL
```

In your case, this statement should select nothing, because SAP normally stores *space* for empty character values.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use:

```
AND a~stblg EQ SPACE
```

--

Talha

Comment: That is correct in most of the cases but i recommend you to use SPACE, thats how abap dictionary recommends.